# SQL: SAP Hana if parameter is null, ignore where

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, hana, hana-sql-script

I'm passing 3 parameters into my Hana Stored Procedure to use as `WHERE` clauses, and if the parameter is `null`, I want the procedure to behave as though that condition doesn't exist.

example:

if one of the input parameters is `deviceType.`

```
SELECT TOP 5 DISTINCT USERS FROM MYTABLE
WHERE USERDEVICE = deviceType;
```

if deviceType is null, query should simply be

```
SELECT TOP 5 DISTINCT USERS FROM MYTABLE.
```

I know I can achieve this with if statements, but is there another way to do it?

Comment: This would normally be done using dynamic SQL (not too recommended for time-critical queries and/or highly frequent execution). You build your query as a string (including the conditions if the parameters are passed) and then execute it (check the exact syntax my MS-SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SQLScript you can use the APPLY_FILTER() function.

E.g.

```
drop procedure getTopUsers;
create procedure getTopUsers (IN filter_cond NVARCHAR(200)) as
begin

  vUsers = SELECT DISTINCT user_name, creator FROM USERS;

  if (:filter_cond is NULL)  then
     TopUsers = select TOP 5 user_name FROM :vUsers;
  else
     tTopUsers = APPLY_FILTER(:vUsers, :filter_cond);
     TopUsers = SELECT TOP 5 user_name FROM :tTopUsers;
  end if;

  SELECT user_name FROM :TopUsers;
end;



call getTopUsers ('CREATOR != ''SYS'' ');
call getTopUsers (NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the requirement is to not apply any condition is `deviceType IS NULL`. Instead of altering the query dynamically, you could just construct a condition that always returns true in such a situation by using the logical `or` operator:

```
SELECT TOP 5 DISTINCT USERS 
FROM   MYTABLE
WHERE  deviceType IS NULL OR USERDEVICE = deviceType;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @deviceType VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(256)
    ,@sql1 VARCHAR(256) = 'WHERE USERDEVICE = ''' + @deviceType + ''''

SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 5 DISTINCT USERS FROM MYTABLE'
SET @SQL = CASE 
        WHEN @deviceType IS NULL
            THEN @SQL
        ELSE @SQL + ' ' + @sql1
        END

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: i didn't assigned a value to @deviceType parameter default is null so if u want to check with value u can asssign the value

Comment: the above is T-SQL syntax for MS SQL Server and doesn't work on SAP HANA